# Deleting duplicate subscribers using max uuid postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to eliminate duplicate subscribers from the subscribers table for a api_customer_id, this is the query that I use to get those duplicate subscribers :

```
select subscribers.email, count(*) from subscribers
inner join subscriptions on subscriptions.subscriber_id = subscribers.id
inner join subscription_lists on subscription_lists.id = subscriptions.subscription_list_id
where 793 in (subscribers.api_customer_id, subscription_lists.api_customer_id) 
group by subscribers.email
having count(*) > 1
```

I tried to delete everything that is not max(subscribers.id), but I could not because the id column type is `uuid`. Here is that error :

```
ERROR:  function max(uuid) does not exist
LINE 1: select max(subscribers.id), subscribers.email, count(*) from...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

What can I do in the meantime to get rid of the duplicates? 
There is created column on the subscribers, but the times are very close together that I'm fearful to use that to max/min on. Any other suggestions?

**Update 1:**

Per question in the comments I do have another column updated at too, they look like this :

[image]

But they're all in the same second, and it's still risky. I don't have the flexibility to change this design now, maybe I can going forward.

Comment: Do you have any column like recently updated or recently accessed that you can use as a fallback comparison for your created date? And are you able to change the table design? I have seen recommendations for using a serial id as the primary key, while keeping a second uuid column for purposes like web/api urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic method that works as long as there is a lower-than operator on the column used to discriminate  (which is the case of `uuid`).

```
WITH dups as (
  select email, id FROM...< complete this with the duplicates detection>
)
DELETE FROM subscribers USING dups
WHERE dups.email = subcribers.email
  AND dups.id < subscribers.id;
```

You may replace `id` by a creation timestamp if these timestamps are guaranteed to be different. Even if they're not different, meaning there are (email,timestamp) duplicates, they will just be not touched by this DELETE. You can then do a second pass with another DELETE, this time with the `uuid` as the differentiator as in the query above. If the timestamps were all different this 2nd pass will delete nothing, otherwise it will finish the job.

Also you may do this in a transaction and check if there are still duplicates and the number of deleted rows seem good before doing a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: hi @Daniel Vérité I think timestamps should be different by a few ms (I updated my question). Is there a way I can verify that they are different before I commit to this solution?

Comment: @Echotest: please see the update.

Comment: < complete this with the duplicates detection> I can't get ids here because I'm grouping by email, emails are same not ids

Comment: @Echotest: you may use a subquery: `select email, [other columns] from subscribers where email in (select email FROM subscribers.... WHERE... GROUP by email having count(*)>1)`